# Resize scrollbar in JScrollPane when drawing with Java2D graphics?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, java-2d

I have a JScrollPanel with viewport on a JPanel.
I want to do something really simple: draw little vertical lines in this fashion:
| | | | | | | | | |

I'm doing this by painting each of these lines on the Jpanel
And when there are too many of them, the horizontal scroll bar would appear accordingly in order to scroll right to see the last ones...

My scrollpane won't resize its horizontal scroll bar and the little bars that are too numerous just overflow the screen and are not displayed...

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the preferred size of your panel, and call revalidate(). [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html#update) is an example.